# just cant login as admin to wordpress backend because of OAuth error

Tags: wordpress, authentication, oauth

I used OAuth for login with google ID using wordpress plugin using login
After providing necessary inputs.. logged out.

Now not able to login since redirect mistake ...
not able to correct as could not login to my wordpress site as admin

by mistake, OAuth deleted.. How to login now in absence of OAuth... I am lost

Comment: Please do not post links to error messages that will be resolved when the question is answered.  Instead, post the error message in the body of the actual question.  And just login via ftp or cPanel file manager and delete the plugin (or rename its folder) that is causing the lockout.

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help.